# Разница между методами класса и методами экземпляра

Tags: ооп, delphi

В чем разница между методами класса и методами экземпляра в Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методы класса не могут использовать `Self` (указатель на текущий объект) и поля объекта. То есть, могут делать все что угодно, что не связано с текущим объектом.
Методы объекта имеют возможность использовать `Self` и могут манипулировать полями. Для использования методов класса объект создавать не нужно, для методов объекта - нужно.